# Why does Axios not working with FormData?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, form-data

I'm using `Axios` & `FormData` to send data to a server in a Vue.js project.
It used to work before, but currently, whenever I send a `formData` object, It doesn't seem to be appended:

Mock server:

[image]

Chrome dev tools:

[image]

(Notice content-length is 2 and FormData is missing)

```
    let url = "https://benben.free.beeceptor.com/1"
    const fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('key', 'value')
    return axios.post(url, fd, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
```

**Things I've tried:**

1. Look for the payload in: chrome/firefox/edge dev tools & in a mock server.
2. Send simple JSON instead of FormData - it works.
3. Send with and without the header - doesn't change anything.
4. Check if the data is appended to FormData successfully - it is (key-value exists).
5. Tried other Stackoverflow solutions. Nothing worked so far.
6. Updating axios.
7. Using the direct axios API (passing an object to axios).

**Note:** I need FormData, because I need to upload a file.

Let me know if any other code samples would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/X02QZN1 — I can't reproduce the problem when I copy/paste your code.

Comment: For me it also work copy pasting, both in firefox and chrome. I would try it in another environment (maybe a very simple html biolerplate, without compilation) as a starting point

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If you think it will be helpful for others to know this, remove the end of the question and post it as an answer to your question instead. It's absolutely fine to answer your own question here on SO, provided you think the question and answers will be useful to people in the future. Or if you don't think it's useful for others in the future, you can delete the question with the "delete" link under the tags. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out - I'm using `snakecaseKeys` package to manipulate the data before sending. It seems not to play well with FormData objects.

```
import snakecaseKeys from 'snakecase-keys'
axios.defaults.transformRequest = [(data) => {
    if (data) {
        return snakecaseKeys(data, { deep: true })
    }
}, ...axios.defaults.transformRequest]
```

Thanks for the comments guys!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, you can side-step the transformations in you transformRequest using `instanceof`.

```
  transformRequest: [
    (data) => {
      if (data instanceof FormData) return data;
      // otherwise, transform your data
      return transformedData;
    },
  ],
```

Answer (score -2):

in React the form should also have encType="multipart/form-data"   attribute, may be in vue also?

Comment: The `enctype` attribute has no effect when the data is being harvested with client-side JS for Ajax (and this example doesn't even get its data from a form in the first place).